# Tracking Code to Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, contactbuilder, einstein-recommendations

Did anyone know how to import userInfo from tracking code data to DATA Extension?

From now we had achieved to review our tracking code records from Personalization Builder=>reporting=>contacts, however, We have no idea how to import those data to data extension.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the [documentation her](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_integration_with_contact_builder.htm&type=5)e, on how you can work with data collected in Collect Tracking Code. A.o. adding it to Contact Builder

Your specific question, about enabling data to Data Extension, this has been a self service solution since earlier this year, so you can enable this integration yourself. Just follow these steps:

> 1. Navigate to the Status tab in Personalization Builder.
> 2. Click gear icon
> 3. Click Data Extension Settings.
> 4. Toggle on Enable Einstein Data Extensions
> 5. Click Save.

as per [this article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_enable_pb_data_extensions.htm&type=5).

Before you can proceed with step 4, you need to have uploaded a valid catalogue and have valid track item calls coming into the system.

```
<script type="text/javascript">       
   _etmc.push(["setOrgId", "MID"]);       
   _etmc.push(["trackPageView", { "item" : "INSERT_PRODUCT_CODE" }]);    
</script>
```

The item ID (represented as *INSERT_PRODUCT_CODE* in the above example) must be present in your uploaded catalogue, for the tracking to be successful.

Once both prerequisites are in place, you will be able to toggle the switch.

Please be aware, that additional user attributes will not be passed to IGO_PROFILES data extension. Only the value you pass in the standard setUserInfo call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">       
   _etmc.push(["setOrgId", "MID"]);     
   _etmc.push(["setUserInfo", {"email": "INSERT_EMAIL_OR_UNIQUE_ID"}]);     
   _etmc.push(["trackPageView"]);    
</script>
```

Comment: Hello @Lukas Lunow,
I have go to step 4 that the toggle is not able to move, that's why we are confusing.
Thank you.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect this

Comment: Let me know if this helps you, and please mark the answer as accepted if it does

Comment: @LukasLunow I thought it was either catalog or streaming, but not both?

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to cover this one. First of all I like this question and I wanted to achieve this by my own but there were different things which were more important.

How I would try to get these infos:

- Query the dataextension IGO_PROFILES

  - Now you have the favourite 5 attributes of a customer + emailvalue + user_id + city + region and country.
- Query the dataextension IGO_VIEWS with the user_id value you received from IGO_PROFILES

  - (i don't know if there can be multiple user_ids attached to the same email value, but i believe that there can be multiple ones)
- Query the dataextension IGO_PURCHASES with the user_id value you received from IGO_PROFILES
- Query the dataextension PI_CONTENTVIEWS with the user_id value you received from IGO_PROFILES

Now you should have the purchases aswell as the views and the surface of the affinity profile (not the deeper one though [:(])

What i believe should be possible, but salesforce might now allow it or there is no external api for it:

- Show full profile (at the end of the page) can be requested if you
  know the email and user_id aka _id value of the contact you want to
  get the information from.
- I imagine that there should be a soap / rest call to retrieve it but i believe that there currently is no api in place